# NSMachBootstrapServer is deprecated, how can NSXPCConnection be used to register a Mach Service?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xpc, mach, nsxpcconnection

I need to write a Mach Service that both my app and a system plugin can talk to, I use the `NSMachPort` API to create a new port, then register it with `NSMachBootstrapServer`:

```
- (void) run
{
    NSMachPort *serverPort = (NSMachPort *)[NSMachPort port];
    [serverPort setDelegate:self];
    [serverPort scheduleInRunLoop:NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [NSMachBootstrapServer.sharedInstance registerPort:serverPort name:@"com.example.MyApp"];

    [NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop run];
}
```

Clang complains that `NSMachBootstrapServer` has been deprecated:

```
warning: 'NSMachBootstrapServer' is deprecated: first deprecated in macOS 10.13 - Use NSXPCConnection instead
```

How does one use `NSXPCConnection` to replace the functionality of `NSMachBootstrapServer` when writing a non-XPC mach service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's true: `NSMachBootstrapServer` class and the majority of its companion classes are [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmachbootstrapserver) in macOS 10.13 High Sierra.

> In macOS 10.14 Mojave and higher you have to use a `NSXPCConnection` API, that is the `Foundation` module's part. It's described in the header file `NSXPCConnection.h`. At the moment it consists of the four main classes:

- [NSXPCConnection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpcconnection)
- [NSXPCInterface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpcinterface)
- [NSXPCListener](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpclistener)
- [NSXPCListenerEndpoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpclistenerendpoint)

Here's how a XPC Connection process looks like:

[image]

And as you can see on a picture, you have to implement a listener.

Here's how a Swift code snippet with listener might look like:

```
let listener = NSXPCListener(machServiceName: "Name-of-Sample.Helper")
listener.delegate = delegate
listener.resume()
RunLoop.current.run()
```

Here's how an Obj-C code snippet with listener might look like:

```
self.listener = [[NSXPCListener alloc] initWithMachServiceName:@"Name-of-Sample.Helper"];
self.listener.delegate = self;
[self.listener resume];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
```

> **If you look at [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41901512/xpc-between-two-cocoa-applications-in-workspace-the-nsxpcconnection-is-immediat) you'll find out how to properly implement all the necessary XPC Connection's objects**.

and...

> **If you look at [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040765/communicate-with-another-app-using-xpc) you'll also find out how it can be used with a Mach Service (there's GitHub [link](https://github.com/brenwell/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample))**.

Comment: This is for an app and a service? I want to make one windowed app, talk to another windowed app. How can i do this? Let me know if i should ask a separate question.

Comment: Yes. ask a separate question, please.